# Why a dictionary object become null suddently without any Assignment?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

_globalData defined at prjectinfo class, it was simple before, but to debug i add more lines

```
protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _globalData;
protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> globalDict
{
    get
    {
        if (_globalData == null)
        {   
            // it had value when it run, but suddent become null without reason and I set a break here.

            SEOData.Instace.loadGlobalDict();   // it is for debug, without it still null issue

            globalDict =  SEOData.Instace.globalDict;   // it is for debug,  try to reassigment, but sometimes keep get null later  sometimes not
        }
        return _globalData;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)  
        {
              // it is for debug    here never break before object is null.
        }
        _globalData = value;
    }
}
```

globalData is init by globalOption object that is done when sofware boot, so it never been assign again.

```
internal ProjectIniInfo( Ini iniInfo, Ini configData, ConcurrentDictionary<string,object> globalData, FindProjectByGuid finder )
     : base( iniInfo )
{
    T1Finder  = finder;
    globalIni = configData;
    this.globalDict = globalData; // when it become null, i check the origin value, that is globalData, it STILL HAVE VALUE. so referenced object not be crash.
```

It is do have value a globalData.Count is 2. but after some random time, it suddently become null and stop at breakpoint i set.

Only globalData been used is at below, indexer is call in another thread, i add some lock no luck, but it only been used here except it is inited when tool boot.

```
public KeyValuePair<string, string> indexer
{
    get
    {
        if (this["Index Use Globall Option", EngineSection.Project_Options.get()] == "uncheck")
        {
            string line = this["Index", EngineSection.Project_Options.get()];
            string[] indexlist = line.Split03();
            foreach (var item in indexlist)
            {
                string[] arr = item.Split05();
                if (arr.Length == 2 && arr[1] == "checked")
                {
                    var v = globalDict.Where(a => (a.Value as Indexing).LinkName == arr[0]).ElementAt(0);
                    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>((v.Value as Indexing).LinkName, (v.Value as Indexing).Key);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var c = _globalData;
            foreach (var item in globalDict)
            {
                Indexing index = (Indexing)item.Value;
                if (index.IsEnabled)
                    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(index.LinkName, index.Key);
            }
            return default(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
        }
        return default(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
    }
}
```

I try to guess  globalDict.Where let it become null, because it only used here. 
or it is possible thread sync issue?

indexer only was called here

```
KeyValuePair<string,string> validindex = default(KeyValuePair<string,string>);

lock (ISeoCore.Instance.SeoData.ProjectSyncRoot)
{// lock or not lock does not help
    validindex = project.indexer;
    if (validindex.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)))   // 没有设置有效的index
        continue;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a tag indicating what language we are talking about here?

Comment: added c# dot net 4.0

Comment: Looks to me like your object is being garbage collected. How is `ProjectIniInfo` being used/persisted?

Comment: no, the origin object still have object, please check 2nd code sinppet  comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no better leads, a possible thread sync issue seems worth investigating.  Try putting locks around the contents of `globalDict`'s `get` and `set` methods.

Comment: set never called before object been null, i set breakpoint at set.        so if only get called, read only will net get thread sycn issue , right?